# Why do we only include header files but not source files?

Tags: c, gcc

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdio.c>  stdio.c is not needed but why?

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

To use `printf` and make the program compile, we add `#include <stdio.h>`. But we know that `.h` is just header files and real definition of `printf` is in `stdio.c`, so why we don't need to include it like the header as `#include <stdio.c>`? and how does the linker even produce executable object file without the essential `stdio.c` being included?

Comment: Because the C-library contains pre-compiled versions of the library functions that are then linked with your source file by the linker.

Comment: You need to differentiate between header files, source files, object files, and library files. A header file typically contains *declarations*, which tells the compiler "the function `printf` exists *somewhere*". The definition (implementation itself) isn't needed. Another important concept to learn is about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: The header just says that somewhere will a `printf` function be implemented and the linker then searches while linking all reachable libs for an implementation for the function `printf`. The reason you don't include `stdio.c` is because you don't want to duplicate the implementation of `clib` into every executable on the computer, the clib is dynamicly linked for most executables.

Comment: check this out, it might help you: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html

Comment: Also, the location of the definition of a function, and the name of the header file declaring the function, have no relationship. The standard C library implementation might have a `printf.c` file for implementing the `printf` function (or maybe even only a *part* of it). This is then built into an object file (`printf.o`) which is used to the create the library itself (together with many other object files).

Comment: If you want to look at the current source for the *master* branch for gcc, `printf()` is actually implemented through [`_vsprintf_internal.c`](https://sourceware.org/git?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c;h=e01c319b19ab1948f34d71f5d12f874cfd2d1cd9;hb=refs/heads/master) The complete [GCC Tree](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;h=refs/heads/master;hb=refs/heads/master) can be found in their `sourceware.org/git` repository. (and note, things are subject to renaming and moving around on a somewhat annoyingly frequent basis....)

Answer (score 3):

Technically, there is nothing stopping you from `#including` a source file. The include directive simply copy-pastes the contents of the header file into the source file before the next compilation step. If you were to `#include` a C file, it would still do the same thing. But then, if you wanted all your code in one translation unit, you wouldn't have split them up into multiple files in the first place. That we `#include` only header files and not C files is more of a convention than something that the language mandates. Rarely, you can see code out there that `#includes` C files to handle some special cases.

Coming to your second question, the contents of what you call 'stdio.c' is available already, shipped with your compiler in binary form as the C standard library. The linker implicitly links with the standard library even though you do not specify this when compiling and linking your code.

Comment: so you mean , C compiler drivers always pass C standard library to the linker? if yes, is a staitc library `libc.a` or a shared library  `libc.so` being used by default?

Comment: @slowjams Depends heavily on your compiler and the platform for which you are compiling. I think gcc on linux defaults to `.so`.

Comment: @slowjams - yes libc is always part of the linking process even though you don't explicitly say `-libc`. In fact to get rid of it you must do so with a special `-nostdlibs` option. Then, and only then, can you keep the C library from liking with your code.

Answer (score 1):

The linker does not care about any `#include`'s you make. It links the libraries you tell it should link to, normally given as command line arguments.
On Linux, not sure about Windows or Mac, you can test this by using a function from `math.h`. The math functions are usually in `libm.so` while the other functions of the C-standard are in `libc.so`. `libc.so` is linked per default, `libm.so` is not linked per default. That is why you normally need to add the `-lm` flag to GCC when you use math functions.

```
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
  //use volatile so GCC does not optimize exp() out
  volatile double v=3;
  return exp(v);
}
```

If you try to compile and link it with `gcc ./main.c -o test` you get an error, you need to add the `-lm` flag. After linking you can check the used shared libraries with `readelf -d test | grep lib` and you see that the program needs `libm.so` or `libm.so.6` and `libc.so` or `libc.so.6`. If you run the program, the libraries will be loaded and used. The definitions of the linked objects are not included in your program when you use dynamic linking (default for libraries).

Answer (score 1):

I've come across several projects which actually do `#include` source files, usually this is to squeeze every last drop of performance to avoid some extra jumps or allowing the compiler to optimize/inline functions, or to do some preprocessor trickery on the "included" source file.

Generally speaking, however, header files contain symbol declarations and structure definitions which may inform the compiler about how functions are to be called and how structure members are arranged in memory.

The actual definition of symbols, as other have mentioned, resides in other objects and are resolved by the linker.

It's important to note that the dynamic linker has two main functions:

- The link/compile-time linker creates an index of symbols required and metadata related to finding these symbols.
- The runtime linker, invoked when the application is executed, will locate the relevant objects and map the symbols provided with the symbols required.

That being said, the source code of `printf` is not required until the application is actually launched.

Comment: The *object* code of `printf` is not required until the application is actually launched. The *source* code of `printf` was required when the standard library was compiled.

Answer (score 0):

> how does the linker even produce executable object file without the essential `stdio.c` being included?

The standard library functions have already been compiled into one or more libraries stored in a well-known location, and those are automatically linked by the compiler.

There are several practical reasons why we typically do not `#include` source files into each other:

1. It doesn't scale very well.  Real projects can contain hundreds to thousands of distinct functions adding up to several hundred thousand to millions of lines of code.  Attempting to process all of that as a single translation unit can result in very long build times (up to several hours, and no that's not an exaggeration), and it's possible for a translation unit to be too large for a compiler to handle.  It also means that *any* change, no matter how minor or localized, requires a full rebuild of the entire project.  Incremental builds would not be possible.

   You have to be very careful how you manage dependencies between modules - it's easy to wind up with circular dependencies that are difficult to resolve.  For example, you have functions in module A that depend on definitions in module B, and functions in module B that depend on definitions in module C, but functions in module C depend on definitions in module A.  If you write

   ```
   #include "C.c"
   #include "B.c"
   #include "A.c"
   ```

   then you'll get an error that the functions in module C are missing stuff from module A.  If you write

   ```
   #include "A.c"
   #include "C.c"
   #include "B.c"
   ```

   then the dependency of C on A is resolved, but now A doesn't have the definitions from B that it requires.

   Splitting declarations off into separate `.h` files helps resolve this problem.

   While C doesn't have a concept of "public" vs. "private" vs. "protected", it does allow you to limit the visibility of function and object names to the current source file with the `static` keyword.  This is handy for creating helper functions or variables for maintaining state between function calls that aren't visible to the rest of the program.  If you include all source files in each other, though, then everything is visible to everything else, which also increases the possibility of name collisions.

Breaking code up into independently compiled modules also makes testing easier, it makes code reuse easier, it makes upgrades easier, etc.